# Should the return of a Python function be an equation or a local variable?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple Python version 2.7 function, call it det2x2 shown in the following code:

```
def det2x2(a, b, c, d):
    return a*d - b*c
```

Is it more Pythonic or recommended to do it this way instead?

```
def det2x2(a, b, c, d):
    result = a*d - b*c
    return result
```

I realize that for this simple function, it may not matter, but for more elaborate calculations it might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example you are creating a reference 'result', then in the next line returning the value of that reference.

So just return the value instead.

```
def det2x2(a, b, c, d):
    return a*d - b*c
```

2 reasons to do it this way:

A. less code to read (main reason)

B. slightly less memory

```
import sys
def det2x2(a, b, c, d):
     result = a*d - b*c
     print sys.getsizeof(result)
     return result
>>> det2x2(1, 2, 3, 4)
24  # you just used 24 bytes of memory for 'result' reference
-2  # answer
```